# Добавление css класса при определенном параметре

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css

Всем доброго вечера.

У меня есть ссылка в виде

```
<a href="#" data-bind="page-href:'user/notifications'" class="nav_el icon ico_msgs /*isset_msg*/" title="Messages"><span class="msgs_value" data-bind="    text: countOfNewMessages, visible:countOfNewMessages() > 0"></span></a>
```

Иконка сообщений на которой отображается количество сообщений, если они есть, если сообщений 0, то цифра не показывается.

Вопрос:

как можна сделать чтобы, если `countOfNewMessages() > 0` то к css добавлялся isset_msg и ссылка имела вид

```
<a href="#" data-bind="page-href:'user/notifications'" class="nav_el icon ico_msgs isset_msg" title="Messages"><span class="msgs_value" data-bind="    text: countOfNewMessages, visible:countOfNewMessages() > 0"></span></a>
```

а, если `countOfNewMessages() = 0`, то

```
<a href="#" data-bind="page-href:'user/notifications'" class="nav_el icon ico_msgs" title="Messages"></a>
```

?

Спасибо!

Comment: > то цыфра не показуется

то **цифра** не **показывается**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="page-href:'user/notifications', css: { nav_el: true, icon: true, ico_msgs: true, isset_msg: countOfNewMessages() > 0 }" title="Messages"><span class="msgs_value" data-bind="text: countOfNewMessages, visible:countOfNewMessages() > 0"></span></a>
```

**Документация: [The "css" binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html)**

Answer (score -1):

Я конеш не профессор, но попробуй так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if(countOfNewMessages > 0) $("a[title = Messages]").addClass("isset_msg");
}
```